# Not able to run a Dash app on Microsoft Azure

Tags: python, azure, plotly-dash

I have built a small Dash app in Python and was successfully able to deploy it on Heroku. The link is here: https://covid19-datachallenge-uconn.herokuapp.com/

However, I tried doing the same on Microsoft Azure and I am getting the following error. I am using this link to do the deployment: https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/deploying-dash-to-azure-app-service/

```
2020-04-02T22:09:27.884279395Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2020-04-02T22:09:27.884282895Z Python 3.7.5
2020-04-02T22:09:27.884286595Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2020-04-02T22:09:27.945960082Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2020-04-02T22:09:27.957890157Z App Command Line not configured, will attempt auto-detect
2020-04-02T22:09:27.958488560Z Launching oryx with: -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -bindPort 8000
2020-04-02T22:09:27.961805781Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20200114.13, Commit: 204922f30f8e8d41f5241b8c218425ef89106d1d, ReleaseTagName: 20200114.13
2020-04-02T22:09:27.963589692Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2020-04-02T22:09:27.963980095Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2020-04-02T22:09:27.964420697Z Build Operation ID: bb8a66d5-6773-4d7e-b210-6f10ca6ab9f8
2020-04-02T22:09:28.553535793Z Detected an app based on Flask
2020-04-02T22:09:28.870188279Z Generating `gunicorn` command for 'application:app'
2020-04-02T22:09:29.171148066Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2020-04-02T22:09:29.368125402Z WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.
2020-04-02T22:09:29.368839706Z WARNING: Could not find package directory /home/site/wwwroot/__oryx_packages__.
2020-04-02T22:09:29.575754204Z [2020-04-02 22:09:29 +0000] [37] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-04-02T22:09:29.577338814Z [2020-04-02 22:09:29 +0000] [37] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (37)
2020-04-02T22:09:29.577878817Z [2020-04-02 22:09:29 +0000] [37] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-04-02T22:09:29.585273464Z [2020-04-02 22:09:29 +0000] [40] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 40
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733903996Z [2020-04-02 22:09:29 +0000] [40] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733937196Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733943196Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733947796Z     worker.init_process()
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733951396Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733963096Z     self.load_wsgi()
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733967196Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733970996Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733974496Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733978196Z     self.callable = self.load()
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733981596Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733985396Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733988897Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733992597Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733996097Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-04-02T22:09:29.733999897Z     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-04-02T22:09:29.734003497Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-04-02T22:09:29.734007097Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-04-02T22:09:29.734010597Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-04-02T22:09:29.734014597Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-04-02T22:09:29.734018197Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-04-02T22:09:29.734021797Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2020-04-02T22:09:29.734025397Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2020-04-02T22:09:29.734029097Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-04-02T22:09:29.734032797Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/application.py", line 2, in <module>
2020-04-02T22:09:29.734036497Z     import dash
2020-04-02T22:09:29.734039997Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash'
2020-04-02T22:09:29.738362924Z [2020-04-02 22:09:29 +0000] [40] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 40)
2020-04-02T22:09:29.782459201Z [2020-04-02 22:09:29 +0000] [37] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-04-02T22:09:29.783424607Z [2020-04-02 22:09:29 +0000] [37] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.


2020-04-02 22:09:30.001 ERROR - Container covid19-datachallenge-uconn_0_8ceb9c66 for site covid19-datachallenge-uconn has exited, failing site start
2020-04-02 22:09:30.004 ERROR - Container covid19-datachallenge-uconn_0_8ceb9c66 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2020-04-02 22:09:30.014 INFO  - Stoping site covid19-datachallenge-uconn because it failed during startup.
```

I can see that it is happening because it is unable to import dash. The app is running fine is my localhost and virtual environment (as created for azure deployment as per the blog)

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, the module "dash" is missing. If you install it via requirements.txt it should work or moreover show you another (new) error which could probably bring more light on the problem situation.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure web app Configuration setting provide Startup command as **gunicorn application:app.server -b :8000**

[image]